# What's the equivalent of GuzzleHttp\Event\SubscriberInterface in Guzzle 6?

Tags: php, guzzle6, guzzle

In Guzzle 5.3 you can use [event subscribers](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/events.html#event-subscribers) as in the following example:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Event\EmitterInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Event\SubscriberInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Event\BeforeEvent;
use GuzzleHttp\Event\CompleteEvent;

class SimpleSubscriber implements SubscriberInterface
{
    public function getEvents()
    {
        return [
            // Provide name and optional priority
            'before'   => ['onBefore', 100],
            'complete' => ['onComplete'],
            // You can pass a list of listeners with different priorities
            'error'    => [['beforeError', 'first'], ['afterError', 'last']]
        ];
    }

    public function onBefore(BeforeEvent $event, $name)
    {
        echo 'Before!';
    }

    public function onComplete(CompleteEvent $event, $name)
    {
        echo 'Complete!';
    }
}
```

What would be the equivalent example in Guzzle 6?

As I've `phpunit` tests which are using `onBefore`/`onComplete` and `onError` event subscribers and the files needs to be upgraded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Guzzle 6 you must add your event class / functions like this:

```
$handler = HandlerStack::create();
$handler->push(Middleware::mapRequest(array('SimpleSubscriber','onBefore');
$handler->push(Middleware::mapResponse(array('SimpleSubscriber','onComplete');

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client($options);
```

and you class should look like this:

```
class SimpleSubscriber
{

    public function onBefore(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        echo 'Before!';
        return $request;
    }

    public function onComplete(ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        echo 'Complete!';
        return $response;
    }
}
```

You can read this in [UPGRADING.md](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#migrating-to-middleware) from Guzzle.

Read [guzzly options](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html) to understand what you can do with `$options`.

Comment: You've forgotten the declaration of the `options` variable which should be set as follow : `$options = ['handler' => $handler];`

Comment: I added a linkt to the options documentation now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example code which is equivalent to `onBefore` event:

```
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;

class SimpleSubscriber {
    public function __invoke(RequestInterface $request, array $options)
    {
        echo 'Before!';
    }
}
```

<sup>Source: [`7efe898` commit](https://github.com/systemhaus/GuzzleHttpMock/commit/6435fb1016e6b837beaa49d0accf5698076aba3e?diff=split) of [`systemhaus/GuzzleHttpMock`](https://github.com/systemhaus/GuzzleHttpMock) fork of  [`aerisweather/GuzzleHttpMock`](https://github.com/aerisweather/GuzzleHttpMock).</sup>

Related: [How do I profile Guzzle 6 requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31869708/55075)